# Edit text between specific symbols in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, xhtml

I want to enclose parts of xhtml files within quotation marks. It's unmarked dialogue of a story. If it is dialogue, it always ends with a name in parentheses. So, I want to find all paragraphs containing an open parenthesis "("  and enclose everything between `(` and the previous `<p>` with another symbol.

If a line looks like this;

```
<p> sentence (name)</p>
```

...then I want to enclose everything between the ( and the previous `<p>` in quotation marks, so it looks like this:

```
<p> "sentence" (name)</p>
```

It's important I leave lines alone that look like this, as these are non-dialogue:

```
<p> sentence</p>
```

I set up the basics in powershell as I used that for previous work on these files, see below, but I am unsure how to enclose the content within " " without overwriting it. Here is what I tried:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\*.xhtml' -Recurse | ForEach {
(Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '\<p\>*\(' , '\<p\>\"*\"\(' }) |
Set-Content $_
}
```

Unfortunately I seem to have gotten something wrong, as this only changes one of my files, which is the only outlier with ( right after an opening tag, but ignores all other lines with parenthesis at the end:

```
<p>(TL: Sorry for a bit of late release)</p>
```

changed to:

```
 \<p\>\"*\"\(TL: Sorry for a bit of late release)</p>
```

Which renders the xhtml file unreadable. I fear my approach might be wrong altogether and would love some input on how to make this work. Thank you for using your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that we might want to add multiple capturing groups, then collect our data in those, and replace however might be desired, for instance, with this expression:

```
(<p>)(\s*)([^(]+?)(\s*)(\(.*\))(<\/p>)
```

begin replaced by:

```
$1$2"$3"$4$5$6
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zLpl7N/1/)

#### Advice

[Tsingyi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11653538/tsingyi)'s completed code now looks like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\path*.xhtml' -Recurse | ForEach { (Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '(<p>)(\s*)([^(]+?)(\s*)((.*))(<\/p>)' , '$1$2"$3"$4$5$6' }) | Set-Content $_ }
```

[LotPings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6811411/lotpings) advises that:

To not insert the " repeatedly on successive runs, the 3rd group should also exclude it =>

```
-replace '(<p>)(\s*)([^("]+?)(\s*)(\(.*\))(<\/p>)','$1$2"$3"$4$5$6'
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much! You saved me after lots of headache. My completed code now looks like this:

`Get-ChildItem 'C:\path\*.xhtml' -Recurse | ForEach {
(Get-Content $_ | ForEach { $_ -replace '(<p>)(\s*)([^(]+?)(\s*)(\(.*\))(<\/p>)' , '$1$2"$3"$4$5$6' }) |
Set-Content $_
}`

Comment: To ***not*** insert the `"` repeatedly on successive runs, the 3rd group should also exclude it => `-replace '(<p>)(\s*)([^("]+?)(\s*)(\(.*\))(<\/p>)','$1$2"$3"$4$5$6'`